# React - Last input doesn't save when form is submitted

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that collects input from the user in several input boxes, and on submit I send that data to my backend. However, I see that each time the last input doesn't get sent.
If I add more input, that "lost input" does get sent, so that means it's backlogged somewhere, but I'm not sure how to force the update...

This is the component where user enters data:

```
function SingleSet(props) {
    const setInitialValue = {
        id: props.id,
        weight: props.weight,
        sets: props.sets,
        reps: props.reps,
    }

    const [currentSetValue, updateSetValue] =
    useState(setInitialValue);

    function handleWeightChange(e) {
        // update weight
        const setWithUpdatedWeight = currentSetValue;
        setWithUpdatedWeight.weight = e.target.value;
        updateSetValue(setWithUpdatedWeight);
        // send to fater
        props.handleSetChange(currentSetValue.id, currentSetValue.weight,
        currentSetValue.sets, currentSetValue.reps);
    }
```

Its parent component:

```
function SingleExercise(props) {
    const initialListOfSets = props.setLog;

    const emptySet = {
        id: null,
        weight: null,
        sets: null,
        reps: null,
    }

    const [currentSetList, setSetList] =
    useState(initialListOfSets);
    
    function handleSetChange(id, changedWeight, changedSets,
        changedReps) {
        const changedSetList = currentSetList.map((set) =>
        {
            if (id === set.id) {
                return {...set, weight: changedWeight,
                sets: changedSets, reps: changedReps}
            }
            return set;
        });
        setSetList(changedSetList);
        props.handleExerciseChange(props.id, currentExerciseName,
            currentSetList);
    }
```

Parent of the parent component, where the submit button lives:

```
function WorkoutLog(props) {
    const emptyExercise = {
        id: null,
        exerciseName: 'Squat',
        setLog: [
        {id: null, weight: null, sets: null, reps: null},
      ]
    }

    const initialExerciseList = props.isPrefilled? props.data :
    [createEmptyExerciseWithId()];
    
    const [currentExerciseList, setExerciseList] =
    useState(initialExerciseList);

    function handleExerciseChange(id, changedExerciseName, 
        changedExerciseSetLog) {
            const editedExerciseList =
            currentExerciseList.map((exercise) =>
            {
                if (id === exercise.id) {
                    return { ...exercise,
                        exerciseName: changedExerciseName,
                        setLog: changedExerciseSetLog};
                }
                return exercise;
            });
            setExerciseList(editedExerciseList);
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const response =
        await fetch('http://localhost:5000/new', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(currentExerciseList),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }
```

I set the state in each component where I handled onChange. But setting the state still doesn't update my last input.

Edit: I somehow solved the issue by passing my parent component (where
the submit button is) a COPY of the data rather than my child's State data
(even though the child's data was correct before passing it to the parent... but when I read it in parent, the value was one update behind).

```
function handleSetChange(id, changedWeight, changedSets,
        changedReps) {
        const changedSetList = currentSetList.map((set) =>
        {
            if (id === set.id) {
                return {...set, weight: changedWeight,
                sets: changedSets, reps: changedReps}
            }
            return set;
        });
        setSetList(changedSetList);
        props.handleExerciseChange(props.id, currentExerciseName,
            changedSetList);
        // here I pass changedSetList instead of currentSetList
        // because parent component was not updating properly
        // (was always one change behind), and now somehow
        // it does work.
    }

    function handleNameChange(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // update new name and send to fater
        const changedExerciseName = e.target.value;
        setExerciseName(e.target.value);
        props.handleExerciseChange(props.id, changedExerciseName,
            currentSetList);
        // passing changedExerciseName instead of state name,
        // to fix parent not updating problem.
    }
```

Comment: One issue might be, not creating new objects when modifying the state. Ex: changing it to `const setWithUpdatedWeight = {...currentSetValue, weight: e.target.value};` and then setting the state might help

Comment: thanks @rainversion_3, I tried that but now two of my last inputs don't show up on submit, instead of one. So it's related somehow, but I still don't understand how to fix the issue...